# How to configure a Qt project to reduce dependencies of the compiled binary?

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, qmake, ldd

- MY_OS = KUbuntu 13.10 x86_64
- QT_VERSION = 5.2.0

I have a Qt project that I want to compile. The project is very small, almost HelloWorld.

When I compile it the result  binary I get has so many dependencies that It does not work on a clean KUbuntu 13.10 x86_64 even with Qt libs redistributed!

So I decided to learn some from a different Qt project - [otter-browser](https://github.com/Emdek/otter)
I downloaded the source code and compiled it - the same result as with my project.
For comparison I downloaded [a deb package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/otter-browser/files/otter-browser-alpha1/otter-browser_0.1.01_amd64.deb/download) of otter-browser and extracted  the binary from it.

Here is the ldd output of binary packaged in deb:

```
$ ldd ./otter-browser
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff775fe000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Network.so.5 => not found
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => not found
    libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5 => not found
    libQt5WebKit.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f68cc7dd000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f68cc4d9000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f68cc2c3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f68cbefa000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f68ccb05000)
```

And here is the ldd output than I compiled myself (I have tried CMake and Qmake - no difference, release\debug version - the same)

```
ldd ./otter-browser
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff7cffe000)
    libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5 (0x00007fae9c9f6000)
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 (0x00007fae9c790000)
    libQt5WebKit.so.5 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5 (0x00007fae9a309000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007fae99ac4000)
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007fae99885000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007fae99530000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fae98eab000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fae987de000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fae984ba000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fae981b6000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fae97fa0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fae97bd7000)
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (0x00007fae97973000)
    libQt5Sensors.so.5 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Sensors.so.5 (0x00007fae97735000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fae97517000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fae9730f000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fae970f6000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fae96eeb000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007fae96ce8000)
    libicui18n.so.51 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.51 (0x00007fae968cf000)
    libicuuc.so.51 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.51 (0x00007fae96548000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fae96213000)
    libxslt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1 (0x00007fae95fd6000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fae95c6f000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fae9596e000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fae9571d000)
    libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fae95433000)
    libgstapp-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fae95227000)
    libgstbase-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fae94fd3000)
    libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fae94dc0000)
    libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fae94b9c000)
    libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fae94980000)
    libQt5Quick.so.5 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5 (0x00007fae943eb000)
    libQt5Qml.so.5 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0x00007fae93dde000)
    libQt5Positioning.so.5 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5 (0x00007fae93ba2000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fae93943000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fae9373f000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fae9353c000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fae9cc3a000)
    libicudata.so.51 => /home/ngor/Devel/sdk/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.51 (0x00007fae91df3000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fae91bd4000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fae919b2000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fae91773000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fae9156a000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fae91366000)
    liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x00007fae910e6000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007fae90ec0000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fae90cad000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007fae90aaa000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fae908a4000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007fae906a1000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007fae9048a000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007fae90285000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007fae9007e000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007fae8fe72000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fae8fc6d000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fae8fa67000)
```

The size of binaries is rather small - 2.1 Mb (deb) against 1.6 (compiled by me). This means all those libs are not statically linked into a deb binary (IMHO, otherwise the size would be about 10-15Mb)

So I wonder how can I compile the project to have only Qt Libs and some trivial stuff like libbstdc++, libgcc, libc in dependencies?

If i miss some basic understandings of project deployment please feel free provide some links instead of a long-long answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you reuse the debian packaging?

Comment: I looks like your build has more options turned on.  I see a lot of extra libraries that hint that there are more features built into yours than the deb version. It may features you have enabled (or not disabled), or just a newer code base.

Comment: I tried to build my own Qt libs by setting the most "bundled-in" configuration. No 3rd party modules at all. No luck. The dependences of binary are the same. Could you please specify what "build options" do you mean? I use the same CMakeLists.txt and .pro file as project's author.

Comment: No, I mean, why don't you start off with their command.... and customize that, and see where the difference comes to exist...

Comment: Sorry Laszlo, I did't get the last one